# Preprocessor doesn't work for xcode 4.4.1 in iOS device

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, preprocessor

I defined a preprocessor macros in one of my project's target. Like this:

[image]

My code is like this:

```
#ifdef FREE_VERSION
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myurl.com"]];
#endif
```

It works fine in simulator. But in my device, this doesn't work at all.

Can anybody tell me why? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  What happens?

Comment: Are you sure you are showing us the Target's settings and not the Project setting? Double check. Also, double check that when you configure for the device that you are using Release or Debug and not some other configuration. I use this all the time never had a problem. If its still failing, close the project and shut down Xcode, restart, try again. Xcode has gotten a big flakey in version 4 with the big re-write.